# sed not responding for me

Tags: linux, sed

I'm trying to use sed but can't get it to work. My system is Ubuntu 16.04.2 with GNU sed 4.2.2

I have a folder with numerous text files that I want to edit. From a terminal in that folder I have tried the following (separately - one command at a time).

To remove blank lines from all the files: `sed -i '/^$/d' *txt`

In case the lines include white spaces: `sed -i '/^\s*$/d' *txt`

To remove line 4: `sed -i '4d' *.txt`

In each case, there is no error message in the terminal but the changes do not happen. I've tried the same commands but for an individual file rather than all, so with the filename instead of *.txt, but still no changes achieved.

The only sign of sed being active at all is if I don't do the -i but ask for a new file: sed '4d' fred.txt > fred2.text

The new file fred2 was created - but with line 4 still there!
What am I missing? How can I get sed to actually carry out these commands?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please include the  output of `for f in fred*.txt ; do ls -l $f ; cat -n $f | head -5; done`.

Comment: ... the error you got can be wrong encoding text into your files , because the sed tool sed is a stream editor.

Comment: Thank you. Here is the output: -rw-rw-r-- 1 ray ray 745 Mar 31 16:31 fred2.txt
-rwxrwxrwx 1 ray ray 745 Mar 29 15:14 fred.txtreports : didier@myriad-online.com
ray@ray-desktop:~/Documents/Myriad Documents/Export/Music Export$ iad-online.com
That bit "didier@myriad-online.com" is from a line within the file - not related to what I was trying to change.

Comment: Sorry the above is all in one stream - The comment box doesn't seem to allow new paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the files in more detail, and doing some experimenting, I discovered what the problem was: The text files I was trying to edit with sed had CR line-end characters. When I changed this to LF the sed commands worked fine.
Thank you to those who made suggestions.